# Create Multi Page PDF with UIImage at the Bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiimage

I need to create a multipage PDF with signature (`UIImage`) at the bottom. I would also like to have a line created so that the signature could be on a line. Here's the code I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)saveAsPDF:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    [nameTextField.text drawInRect:CGRectMake(50, 40, 512, 30) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [TextView.text drawInRect:CGRectMake(50, 90, 512, 672) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];

    [SignatureImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(30, 500, 190, 71)];

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* documentNameWithExtention = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", nameTextField.text];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentNameWithExtention];

    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
}
```

So, I need to know how to make it multipage and I need to know how to add the signature at the end of the body text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html)

> The functions you use to create a PDF graphics context allow you to
>   specify a default page size but they do not automatically open a page.
>   After creating your context, you must explicitly open a new page using
>   either the UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage or UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo
>   function. And each time you want to create a new page, you must call
>   one of these functions again to mark the start of the new page. The
>   UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage function creates a page using the default size,
>   while the UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo function lets you customize
>   the page size and other page attributes.